# How to use an OSGI reference from another bundle in java

Tags: java, apache-camel, osgi, jbossfuse, blueprint-osgi

Im working with JBoss Fuse, I have created a bundle that exports a DataSouce and now I want to query it.

There's a reference to said DataSource in the blueprint of another bundle:

```
  <reference 
      id="myDataSource"
      filter="(osgi.jndi.service.name=myDataSouce)" 
      interface="javax.sql.DataSource"
  />
```

How can I access this reference from java code so I can query it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom Bean:

```
<bean id="myDsBean" class="my.company.MyDsBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
</bean>
```

Java code:

```
public class MyDsBean {

    private JdbcTemplate myds;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource ds) {
        this.myds = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    }
    // Code to query data source
}
```

My example is using `JdbcTemplate` but you can substitute that to whatever you want to use.